# Lost audio after upgrading from 13.10 to 14.04

Tags: upgrade, sound, 14.04, pulseaudio, alsa

After the upgrade I've lost the audio output immediately: no hardware change !

With Kubuntu 14.04 Kernel 3.13.0-24-generic (#47-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 2 23:31:42 UTC 2014) - the audio doesn't work at all.

All my ALSA information is located at
http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=9fb68b073380ba8bb16213bef8843b2a6bf54557

The audio drive seems correctly loaded but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please try this http://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/ (PS: your link is incomplete please edit your question)

Comment: I do but no results.

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 sound devices on your pc:
First one is HDMI output,
second one is  the main device which has several faders muted,
( **Note** at the end ).

Two ways to unmute the second device:

**1. Unmute with Pulseaudio volume control:**

- Open Pulseaudio volume control from Applications/sound menu, (if not present, `sudo apt-get install  pavucontrol` )
- Select output device tab
- Scroll down to display the second device.
- Click "set as fallback" button to set it as default device, check "mute" button state, increase volume using the  fader, 
  hopefully you will hear sound.

**2. Unmute using Alsamixer:**

- In a terminal, launch alsamixer.You will see something like    this:
  http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/86/Alsamixer.png
- Press F6 , select the second device (Just in case  you are unfamiliar    with console applications, use arrow keys to highlight
  the 2nd device    then press enter key) .
- Use left/right arrows key  to move around    faders, up/down arrows to increase volume and "m" key to unmute.

**Note**:
Extract from your alsa-info showing  2 devices and muted Master fader:
search in the Amixer output section:

!!Amixer output
!!-------------

!!-------Mixer controls for card 0 [Generic]          *<=== first device*
*....some lines....*
!!-------Mixer controls for card 1 [Generic_1]        *<=== second device*
*....some lines....*
Simple mixer control 'Master',0
*....some lines....*
Mono: Playback 28 [67%] [-21.00dB] [off]              *<==== Master is off*

Comment: The first step was sufficient for me. Also, I found that the volume control in the system tray uses the HDMI channel as the default master channel, meaning that using that volume control to change the volume won't work. Right click it, then click "Select Master Channel..." and select the other channel (for me, it is "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo").