# Ubuntu 14.04 audio problem

Tags: sound, soundcard, sound-blaster

I am new to Ubuntu. Lately I have installed Ubuntu 14.04, everything was working fine. Until I noticed that sound is not working. I searched in google and in different forums and sadly haven't found any solution. 
My motherboard is Gigabyte Sniper M5 with Creative Sound Core 3D chip. I have made an ALSA Information script, here's the link:

http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=d713beeccbdafbc54a70e13c73271ce534dfb4a2

It's the only problem I have, the rest is perfect. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This was the same problem  : [http://askubuntu.com/questions/465695/lost-audio-after-upgrading-from-13-10-to-14-04/467757#467757]